# Is there a repository for Debian stable ("Squeeze") with the latest version of the Chromium browser?

Tags: chromium, debian-squeeze

Is there a repository for Debian stable (squeeze) with latest Chromium browser (Debian has an outdated version 6.x in official stable repository)? So far I have not found any. It is pity that Ubuntu has such repositories, but Debain does not.

I know I could go with Google Chrome, but I do not like the EULA and added "functionality" by Google.

Comment: Related: [The Chrome Web Store doesn't support Chromium on Debian “Squeeze” or other very old Chrome versions. What's the workaround?](http://superuser.com/questions/523852/the-chrome-web-store-doesnt-support-chromium-on-debian-squeeze-or-other-very)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the [latest](http://build.chromium.org/f/chromium/snapshots/Linux/LATEST), bleeding-edge build of [Chromium for Linux](http://build.chromium.org/f/chromium/snapshots/Linux/?C=M;O=D), you can get it from the [Chromium BuildBot](http://build.chromium.org/). (There is also a [64-bit build](http://build.chromium.org/f/chromium/snapshots/Linux_x64/?C=M;O=D) for Linux.) You’ll have to “install” it yourself because it comes as a ZIP file, not a *nix package, but that’s simple enough (especially for Linux users); just unzip it to where your current Chromium install is.

(I’ve been on the [cutting edge](http://build.chromium.org/f/chromium/snapshots/Win/LATEST) of Chromium by doing this for [Windows](http://build.chromium.org/f/chromium/snapshots/Win/?C=M;O=D) for a few years now.)

Comment: Yes, I have already been doing in for some time, but I was hoping there is a Debian way to achieve the same. Also, at times it seems that this bleeding edge is just a bit too much "bleeding". I was hoping to get chromium builds that are equivalent to google-chrome stable.

Comment: I don’t know about Debian packages, but as for the latest version, the buildbot server keeps a few dozen versions at a time, so you can get one from two or three months earlier.